# IE 11 SVG animation smoothness

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, animation, svg

I've got big problem with SVG smoothness on IE 11 (works perfectly on Chrome).

It should work like real-time timeline. SVG element is dynamically increasing it's height, events are shown in it's time and goes down all time. The problem is that moving elements by 1px is visible and looks bad.

On Chrome I resolved this problem by adding `transform: rotate(360deg)` (now also I've got `scale()`) which enabled antialiasing for these elements, and now it's working smoothly there.

Animation on IE isn't smooth unfortunately. I tried positioning elements both by `x`/`y` and `translate()`. Position is calculated precisely each time requesting animation frame. It's more visible on raster images included into (or I just think so). I tried using `shape-rendering`, `text-rendering` (for text) and `image-rendering` for these images.

There is simple JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9ke74mqo/

Has anyone any other idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested I've just resolved it. The problem is that in IE there isn't any possibility to turn on antialiasing by any `svg` element property. When I packed everything in `<g transform="rotate(360)" />` element everything just works fine.